# Characters remain in the window when using COC or Jedi plugin in Vim

Tags: vim, autocomplete

I've been using Vim for about 6 month and finally reached the level where I can't live without it.

I'm really grateful for those who wrote great tutorials or blog posts, and kindly answered easy questions which helped be alot.

Since I started using the autocompletion Plugin, Jedi, **characters from the autocompletion window still remain in main window after the autocompletion window is disappeared.** I thought this problem was only limited to the Jedi Plugin, but after I changed it into COC Plugin, I still experience the same problem.

I've searched quite a lot and couldn't find any thread about this problem and now I'm starting to think this problem is only occuring to me.

Solution to the problem is the best, but I'll be still grateful for any suggestions, link to a other thread.

I attached my .vimrc below.

***Vim 8.2***
***Windows 10***

```
" vim runtime config file
" Written by Knowblesse 2020
" Adapted from miguelgrinberg/.vimrc

"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
"             Basics              "
"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
" Sane text files
set fileformat=unix " uses line ending LF (not DOS-style CR LF)
set encoding=utf-8
set fileencoding=utf-8
" View
set number
set colorcolumn=100
set nowrap
set hlsearch
set relativenumber
set scrolloff=8
set scrolloff=8
set splitright
set clipboard=unnamedplus
" Tab
set tabstop=4
set shiftwidth=4
set softtabstop=4
set expandtab
" Font
if has('unix')
    echo "Unix Mode"
    set guifont=Bitstream\ Vera\ Sans\ Mono\ 12
else
    echo "Window Mode"
    set guifont=Bitstream\ Vera\ Sans\ Mono:h12
endif
"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
"          Key Bindings           "
"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
imap jk <Esc>
nmap <Tab> >>
nmap <S-tab> <<
vmap < <gv
vmap > >gv
map <leader>t :call NERDTreeToggle()<CR>

"remove highlighted
nmap <leader>] : nohlsearch<CR> 

"delete buffer w/o closing the current window
nmap <leader>q :bp\|bd #<CR>

"faster editting
if has('unix')
    nmap <leader>vv :e ~/VCF/vimrc/vimrc.vim <CR>
else
    nmap <leader>vv :e C:\VCF\vimrc\vimrc.vim <CR>
endif
"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
"           Color Scheme          "
"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
syntax on
colorscheme monokai
filetype on
filetype plugin indent on

"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
"             Plugin              "
"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
"monokai theme is manually installed
"ctag is manually installed

call plug#begin()
Plug 'yegappan/taglist'
Plug 'tpope/vim-sensible'
Plug 'mg979/vim-visual-multi'

"buffer lists instead of tab
Plug 'ap/vim-buftabline'

"NERD
Plug 'preservim/nerdtree'

"Git
Plug 'airblade/vim-gitgutter'
Plug 'Xuyuanp/nerdtree-git-plugin'
Plug 'tpope/vim-fugitive'

"Coding
Plug 'davidhalter/jedi-vim'
Plug 'ervandew/supertab'
"Plug 'dense-analysis/ale'
Plug 'itchyny/lightline.vim'

"Color theme
Plug 'joshdick/onedark.vim'

"Table generataion
Plug 'dhruvasagar/vim-table-mode'

"Vertical line generation
Plug 'Yggdroot/indentLine'

" For Testing .....................
"Auto Commplete
Plug 'neoclide/coc.nvim', {'branch': 'release'}
"Arduino
Plug 'stevearc/vim-arduino'


call plug#end()
```

[image]

Red arrows shows remaining characters

[image]

Comment: If you still get those artefacts with the `:help i_ctrl-n` or related commands, use Vim's issue tracker. If you don't, use the plugin's issue tracker.

Comment: This type of display anomalies are often due to issues with the terminal program you're using, or misconfiguration (for example the $TERM variable.) Maybe try a different terminal program to see if the issue is gone there? (At least to narrow it down...)